# Replacement for Ms Access Db for multi-LAN user purpose

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have been using access for my applications from over 4 years now. I realize its time to move on now and i need suggestions for a new database. Here are my requirements :

1. Should be able to connect it with Vb.net windows form frontend GUI - all database functions such as add/delete/edit/update will be done through the vb.net front-end only.
2. Should be able to place the db on LAN and each client on the LAN can then access the centrally stored db through their individual front-ends.
3. At the most 5-6 users will be reading/writing to the database at the same time , so the database should not crash or slow down .
4. Since i come from MS access background, i would like something thats similar to it so that i can learn and adapt to it quickly.
5. Not very important, but i think its worth mentioning. This db will be the main central db for my .net application. My .net application will also be interacting with quickbooks and magento via some apis but ultimately all this data will go to the central db. So just curious, will there be any compataibility issues with the database that you suggest ?
6. Should handle about 10 tables and around 10k records in each table
7. Should be secure - just that i should be able to lock it up or anyhow prevent it being accessed from anywhere else other than the vb.net front-end.

Lastly, I would prefer it to be free to use if possible but not essential.

I realize there are some topics like mysql vs sqllite and on databases, but pls understand i need suggestions for one that will be apt for the purposes i have listed above.

All inputs will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit : Just curious - Would i pushing the limits if i still stick to access - i understand access won't be good for multi-user access but i guess 5 users is not much ?

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic, as [SO is not a recommendation engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/173644).

Comment: Hi, i have read those rules. I completely understand all recommendations will be subjective and i see no issues with that. I dont know why its showing under mysql, can somebody pls move it to the right section. I will appreciate if this topic is opened at least for a day so i can get some inputs and then continue my research from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with SQL server express which adds no cost to your application.  You would have to do some modifications to your application like double quotes that should be replaced by single quote.  also note that any Ms access function in queries will not be compatible like date function.  If you use msaccess form, you can still use them with the data from SQL server.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will not be building any query or report in access, just use it to store data in tables, define the relationships and add some restrictions to data types. All other work such as query functions, edit,save,add,delete etc i will do them from the vb.net front-end. How much of an advantage will it be to use sql server vs acess 2010 ? I have very minimal experience with Sql server, so will the learning curve be steep ?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is the obvious answer, and MS Access has built-in upgrade tools. I do not think you have to look further than that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the scope of what you're doing is pretty small, so I'd say using a new version of access (like 2010) is still a good solution. Access really only tends to start to struggle once you're building large applications inside it or having a large number of users. If you're under ten users I'd say it's still a fine solution.

Alternatively, [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is very similar to access in design and is a great database engine (and free as well!).

Comment: I would definitely counsel against trying to use SQLite with Microsoft Access. The ODBC drivers are dodgy to say the least. Upgrading MS Access might improve performance slightly, but it will not help with most of the issues that you mention.

Comment: @PhilipSheard He's not actually using access as his front end from what I can tell, only as his back end. So if he was to use SQLite it would be to replace Access, not work in conjunction with it....(unless I've misinterpreted his post).

Comment: Thanks Mansfield for your reply. I am glad to know i can still use access. I have no issues in getting access 2010, would it work same with vb.net as with the older versions, can i use ado(not ado.net) ? And yes, the front-end will be vb.net form application ONLY. The backend database (sqlite or ms access ) will just hold the table structure and values and have some predefined rules such as data types and character limitations.

Comment: @techspark I believe you can still use ADO. If you liked my answer, please vote up and select as answer :)

Comment: Thanks - just did :) One quick question, how good is access 2010 compared to 2007/sqlite, any significant changes?

Comment: One of the changes in access 2010 compared to 2007 is the ability to add triggers, where as before you only had the option of intercepting form events.